# UIButton action after custom animation

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I want to have custom animation conected with UIButton, so I have decided to create own class with superclass UIButton. Then i overloaded touchesBegan method like that

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
[UIView animateKeyframesWithDuration:0.5
                               delay:0
                             options: 0
                          animations:^{

                              [UIView addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime:0
                                                      relativeDuration:0.5
                                                            animations:^{
                                                                self.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(self.transform, 0.7, 0.7);
                                                            }];

                              [UIView addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime:0.5
                                                      relativeDuration:0.5
                                                            animations:^{
                                                                self.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
                                                            }];

                          }
                          completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                              [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
                          }];}
```

Animation works fine but nothing happen after. It looks like calling super method doesnt work in completion handler (dont know why). My question is: what can I change to have delayed UIButton action creating own class in similar way ?

EDIT: I want to create own class because i have a lot of buttons in my app and i want them to behave the same.

Comment: What are you expecting to happen after the animation completes?

Comment: You don't need to create a custom button to do this. Just fire the animation on touch down or touch up, with a standard button, and put any code you want to run after the animation in the completion block.

Answer (score 0):

UIButton actions are usually assigned to fire on UIControlEventTouchUpInside which should be worked out in the touchesEnded method and not touchesBegan.